# Will the Ubuntu Touch dev image wipe my bootloader, when installed with the phablet package?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

As title says:

Will the Ubuntu Touch dev image wipe my bootloader, when installed with the phablet package?

Any ideas on how well this will work in HTC Desire?

-Lathrisk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't wipe bootloader. But your bootloader must be unlocked first.

There is no official support for HTC desire.  But porting is possible as the base is cynogenmod 10.

Currently HTC desire is marked as **Sort of working**. You can track the progress here

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Also you may get more info on XDA.